# How can another user run my Python code and access its Dash outcome without sharing source code

Tags: python, remote-access, dashboard

I use Google Colab in which I have defined a (Python 3) function.

When function is called with several selected parameters, it takes source files (CSV) from the Google Drive and executes a code. An outcome of the function is a couple of figures that I visualize using Dash on my local computer.

I want other users, too, to be able to remotely run the source code (ideally placed on Google drive still), define the parameters in a text box, click OK button, and see the dashboard with figures on their computers.

All that without any installation and sharing the sourse code. **Just click on some link, define parameters, confirm them, run my Google Colab notebook, see a dashboard**. Is this even technically possible and if so, how?

I am aware of solutions that involve sharing a source code, creating web pages or apps etc. I would not prefer any of that.
Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: Where is the code supposed to be executed? Google Collab? Some host machine?

Comment: I want to keep the code as Google Collab Notebook on Google Drive (my account). I need to find a way how to access it from users computers. I want them to have just some URL that will begins the whole story.

Comment: Soooo, you don't want a web app but you want an URL?

Comment: I am total beginner in this and cannot answer you better. That is just how I imagine it and ask if it is possible. What would you suggest?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you explained why you need the source code private and why web page and local apps are not viable options. Deployment is an aspect very dependant on specific needs of the solution you are creating.

Comment: I cannot share the code because of my employer policy who wishes to keep the code as local Collab Google notebook. I am looking for the simplest solution both for users and programmers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249474/discussion-between-matszwecja-and-mr-slow).

Comment: So the answer I was looking for is: deploy the App. to a server (Pythonanywhere, Google Cloud Run etc.) as a dockerfile.